# Can't get PMD 5.2.1 to check JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, pmd

Can anyone tell me how to enable JSP checking for PMD?  I have an existing Maven web project that I'm trying to get PMD syntax checking going for.   Pretty typical configuration:

```
/src/main/java (java files here)
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views (jsp files here)
```

I'm using the Maven plugin, version 3.3 (current), which uses PMD 5.2.1.   Theoretically, this includes checking for JSP files, but none of my JSP files are being touched.   (Java file checking works just fine.)

Here's my Maven plugin configuration:

```
    <profile>
        <id>pmd</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                            <include>src/main/**/*.jsp</include>
                        </includes>
                        <rulesets>
                            <ruleset>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/properties/pmd_workspace.xml</ruleset>
                        </rulesets>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>pmd</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Here's the entire console output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.3:pmd (default) @ MyWAR---
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UnnecessaryConversionTemporary instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnnecessaryConversionTemporary. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UnnecessaryFinalModifier instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnnecessaryFinalModifier. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UnnecessaryReturn instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnnecessaryReturn. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UselessOperationOnImmutable instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOperationOnImmutable. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
Dec 19, 2014 6:21:51 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleReferenceNode
WARNING: Use Rule name rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml/UselessOverridingMethod instead of the deprecated Rule name rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOverridingMethod. Future versions of PMD will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#language

There is no way currently to have it check for "jsp" as the source type without modifying the plugin.

You might want to try maven-exec with direct command line options of PMD as short-cut.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

http:://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.1/usage/running.html

Comment: It never occurred to me that the plugin would not support the options that PMD itself supports.   That's somewhat awkward.